# Ext.create returns constructor instead of object

Tags: javascript, extjs

```
Ext.application({
        name: 'test',
        launch: function() {
            var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
                id:'grid',
                renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
                store: userStore,
                width: 400,
                height: 200,
                title: 'Application Users',
                columns: [
                    {
                        text: 'word1',
                        width: 100,
                        sortable: false,
                        hideable: false,
                        dataIndex: 'word1'
                    },
                    {
                        text: 'word2',
                        width: 100,
                        sortable: false,
                        hideable: false,
                        dataIndex: 'word2'
                    }
                ],
                dockedItems: [
                    {
                        xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
                        store: userStore,
                        dock: 'bottom',
                        displayInfo: true
                    }
                ]
            });

            //error here
            grid.reload();
```

I see error in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'reload'

In debugger I see that variable 'grid' has type of 'constructor'

> grid:constructor

So it's no wonder why there is no method 'reload'. It's wonder for me why I'm getting a reference to constructor function instead of reference to newly created object.

The same problem occurs when instantiating another ExtJs core classes.

May it somehow be related to my project structure?

P.S. I'm new to JavaScript, so it will be no surprise for me if the problem is in my poor understanding of core concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the grid has no `reload` method, loading is handled by the store, so you want `grid.getStore().load();`

The first thing to do is check the docs, you'll see there's no reload method on a grid.

Comment: OMG, I feel stupid now :( But can you explain why I see 'constructor' as type of my variable? And one more question: once I reload my store, how should I push the data to grid to display it?

Comment: It's part of the internal class system, so it's just another method. You don't need to do anything, once the store is bound to the grid, the grid listens for when it loads and will update automatically.

Comment: Thanks, I've finally handled it, now it works. The problem was in incoming json. No magic anymore.